# Angular 2 Bootstrap 4 and ng-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am abit confused as to what is the need for [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal) built by angular team if we can use bootstrap 4 class straight out of the box (with containers and modals?) I have been using both ng-bootstrap and bootstrap 4 syntax at various places for not particular reason and it is becoming a mess...Is there a general rule for using either?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the main reasons for using ng-bootstrap would be the **JavaScript compatibility part**.

The regular Twitter Bootstrap relies on jQuery for data manipulation. It also manipulates the state of elements by setting classes such as ".active" or by removing it from an existing element.

On the other hand, ng-bootstrap does NOT require jQuery to run. All the elements are built from ground up using code that would not require jQuery and would play nicely along with Angular Core. It also helps retain the look and feel of Bootstrap components by making use of Bootstrap CSS file.

To summarize, if you use Twitter Bootstrap, you rely solely on jQuery for JavaScript. When you are using ng-bootstrap, you are moving away from jQuery domain completely and you would be relying purely on AngularJS to provide you with the functionality part of it. The only thing that ng-bootstrap and Twitter Bootstrap have in common would be the CSS styling for the elements.

Hope this clears the confusion.

Comment: Yes it does thanks. What is wrong with using the full twitter bootstrap as well as ngbootstrap (Use the best of both in one project)? For example, ng-bootstrap does not provide certain feature that twitter-bootstrap provides, wouldn't it be nice to just copy paste code from twitter bootstrap and use it?

Comment: Yes, it would be nice. But what about the JS part of it? Do you want to copy that too? And if you do, can you ensure that it's not dependent on jQuery? And if you want to copy the appropriate code from jQuery or copy jQuery completely over to the AngularJS project, the purpose of prevent code-bloat is defeated. In fact, you can use jQuery along with other libraries and put them in `assets` folder when working with Angular 2 app. But that will mean that you are NOT harnessing the compete power of Angular. It is both tiresome and time-consuming to migrate over to complete AngularJS, but worth.